# In ros gmapping, how to use Intel Research Lab dataset?

Tags: ros, navigation, rosbag, gmapping, intel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know how to use the Intel Research Lab dataset (.clf).  Should I read the file and publish the lase_scan and tf topic?  If so,how should I do in detail?  thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233042/in-ros-gmapping,-how-to-use-intel-research-lab-dataset?/) by [wang cong](https://answers.ros.org/users/26684/wang-cong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2016-04-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had some time on my hands, so I wrote a script for you: [clf_to_rosbag.py](https://gist.github.com/mintar/d6c0dbd3e9e5dd1b1af0441689607ed7) .

The script converts the .clf file into a rosbag file. The alternative would have been to publish laser_scan and tf, as you suggest, but then we would also have to handle publishing the `/clock` topic (since the data has timestamps from the past). By converting to a bag file, `rosbag --clock` handles this for us.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2016-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wang cong](https://answers.ros.org/users/26684/wang-cong/) on 2016-04-27**:
Thanks. I have converted the .clf file to .bag file by running the  clf_to_rosbag.py .
But when I run the bag file ,open the rviz, no map  received.I input the command: "rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=base_scan" and  it print nothing. I think if it works well ,it should print something . thanks

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2016-04-28**:
It should be `scan:=laser`, not `scan:=base_scan`, since I wrote the laser data on the topic `laser`.

**Comment by [wang cong](https://answers.ros.org/users/26684/wang-cong/) on 2016-04-28**:
Still no map .And in rviz, Map shows no  " No transform from [] to [map]",how to deal with it ? Thanks

**Comment by [wang cong](https://answers.ros.org/users/26684/wang-cong/) on 2016-04-28**:
OK,thanks very much.I have got it. I need to publish a tf  base_link -> base_laser ,and I modify the .py you provided , the tf in it is odom->base_link . Now ,it works.  thanks!

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2016-05-02**:
Glad to help! BTW, you closed the question; I've reopened it, since we usually don't do that here. Please "accept" my answer instead.

**Comment by [wang cong](https://answers.ros.org/users/26684/wang-cong/) on 2016-05-02**:
i don't know how tp accept your answer ,please tell me

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2016-05-02**:
Just click the round checkmark icon next to my answer and **wait a few seconds** until it turns green. Don't click again.

**Comment by [Kyle Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28081/kyle-fan/) on 2016-09-27**:
Hello,can you give me the clf_to_rosbag.py you midified? Thank you!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-27**:
@Kyle Fan: the link to the script is in @Martin Günther's answer above. Just click on the `clf_to_rosbag.py` link.

**Comment by [user_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28458/user_123/) on 2016-11-07**:
Is there any generalized code that can convert any .clf file to .bag format?????? I was trying the same code for 'aces.clf' file after changing the names in the code, but it is giving IO error.

**Comment by [LReddy](https://answers.ros.org/users/28656/lreddy/) on 2016-11-30**:
@wang tiancheng Could you please post the code in which you modified and published the tf